# Как инициализировать объект через список инициализации

Tags: c++, c++11, инициализация

Есть такой класс:

```
class Book {
public:
    char* name;
    char** authors;
    int authorsCount;
    int publishingYear;
    Book(const char* name_,\
         const char* authors[],\
         int authorsCount_, \
         int publishingYear_);
    bool operator < (const Book &other) const;
    void print(void) const;
    ~Book();
};
```

Как правильно(и возможно ли вообще) инициализировать объект этого класса используя список инициализации(Braced initialization)? Вот такой вариант почему-то не работает:

```
Book b = {"Skazki", {"Ivanov", "Petrov"}, 2, 1968};
```

> error: could not convert ‘{"Skazki", {"Ivanov", "Petrov"}, 2, 1968}’
>   from ‘’ to ‘Book’
>        Book b = {"Skazki", {"Ivanov", "Petrov"}, 2, 1968};

Comment: Зачем понадобились эти \ после объявлений параметров конструктора?

Answer (score 4):

Вы пытаетесь инициализировать указатель `const char **authors` при помощи инициализатора `{"Ivanov", "Petrov"}`. Компилятору, разумеется, совершенно не ясно, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Конструировать в такой ситуации временный массив язык не будет.

Чтобы в такой ситуации заставить компилятор сконструировать временный объект типа *массив* из `{}`-инициализатора, придется явно указать перед ним имя "массивного" типа. При этом "сложные" имена типов в таком контексте неупотребимы, т.е. придется сначала завернуть тип *массив* в компактное typedef-имя, например так

```
using A = const char *[];
Book b = {"Skazki", A{"Ivanov", "Petrov"}, 2, 1968};
```

Если бы у вас в конструкторе был параметр типа

```
const char* const (&authors)[2]
```

то компилятор бы самостоятельно расценил ваше `{"Ivanov", "Petrov"}` как инициализатор для временного *массива* типа `const char *[2]`. Но вам этот вариант не подходит, ибо в вашем случае размер массива является значением времени выполнения.

---

Что интересно, GCC не хочет компилировать и вариант с `A{"Ivanov", "Petrov"}`, ибо не разрешает брать адрес временного массива. Причины такого запрета не ясны. Вроде в стандарте его навскидку не видно. И Clang успешно компилирует этот вариант.

Comment: Я тоже наткнулся на это — а _почему_ так? Какая мотивация для компилятора/стандарта не принимать код в исходном виде?

Comment: @VladD: См. первый абзац. Никаких намеков на массив данный код не содержит. `[]` в списке параметров - это просто указатель. Поэтому с чего бы это вдруг тут вообще возникнет тема массива?

Comment: Ага, то есть это потому, что в конструкторе в реальности `char**`, а не `char*[]`. Верно? // Ага, так и есть.

Comment: VladD: Да, конечно. В списке параметров функции `char *[]` - это полный неотличимый эквивалент `char **`.

Comment: Ваши рассуждения не верны с самого начала. Как раз в этой ситуации из `{"Ivanov", "Petrov"}` будет конструироваться массив (с неопределенным временем жизни в С++11, строго временный в С++14), который будет оборачиваться в `std::initializer_list`. При желании его можно было бы использовать для инициализации полей класса принимая `::std::initializer_list<char const *> const authors_` и используя как `authors{authors_.begin()}, authorsCount{authors_.size()}`. Но ничего толкового из этого бы не вышло.

Comment: @VTT: Это откуда у вас такие сведения? Ничего подобного. Синтаксис инициализатора `{...}` не является выражением и не имеет самостоятельной интерпретации "по умолчанию". Интерпретация такого инициализатора полностью определяется "левой частью", т.е. инициализируемой сущностью, по правилам из 8.6.4. В данном случае левая часть - это указатель `const char **`. В такой ситуации никакого массива не конструируется и никакого `std::initilizer_list` не создается. Откуда вы это взяли - не ясно.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых следует изменить поля класса чтобы они могли хранить передаваемые таким образом данные. Указатели `char *` должны быть `const char *` (или `string_view`) так как они указывают на неизменяемые массивы со статическим временем жизни полученные из строковых литералов. Указать `char * *` должен стать контейнером, так как передаваемый массив в любом случае будет временным, а нужно, чтобы он жил на протяжении жизни создаваемого объекта.

```
private: using Authors = ::std::vector<char const *>;

private: char const * m_name;
private: Authors      m_authors;
private: int          m_publishingYear;

public: explicit Book
(
    char const * const                          name
,   ::std::initializer_list<char const *> const authors
,   int const                                   publishingYear
)
:   m_name{name}
,   m_authors{authors}
,   m_publishingYear{publishingYear}
{}

Book b{"Skazki", {"Ivanov", "Petrov"}, 1968};
```

[Online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QOs6DapT9EMp5y8w)